# Subscript font size in Emacs TeX mode

Tags: emacs

In Emacs 23 TeX mode, subscripts and superscripts are displayed in smaller fonts. How can I configure Emacs to turn off this feature and use the same font size for all input?

Comment: Are you able to review the new answer that was posted for its validity? Since there's so much time that has passed, there may be new things that are better.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to turn off using

```
(setq tex-fontify-script nil)
```

in `.emacs`. You can also access it using `customize-mode <ENTER> tex-mode <ENTER>` and scrolling down to "Tex Fontify Script" and clicking on "Toggle".

There are also two control variables which you can set to neutral values to disable the fontification, for example if you just want to make it smaller without raising or lowering, or if you want to keep the raising and lowering without it getting smaller.

```
; This sets the amount of raising/lowering
(setq tex-font-script-display '(0 0))
; This sets how small the font is made relative to the text
(setq tex-suscript-height-ratio 1)
```

(Note: **suscript** is not a typo, it is used to mean "superscript" and "subscript" by `tex-mode`.)

As with `tex-fontify-script`, both of these variables may be customised using `customize-mode`.

---

Now, as far as I've been able to figure out, customising the font face with `customize-face` doesn't seem to work. The height can be altered, but the raising and lowering values are overridden by the code in `tex-mode`, which raises or lowers the text regardless. This happens in the function `tex-font-lock-suscript`. If there is a way to turn that off by setting a custom face then that would be another way of doing this job, but I wasn't able to figure out the correct value.